# How to setup the private blockchain network using Besu?

Tags: besu, hyperledger

Last week, my teacher gave me a Blockchain assignment about "Deploy the private blockchain network using Besu with at least 2 Full nodes and 1 Light node". Incidentally, I found this link [enter link description here](https://besu.hyperledger.org/private-networks/tutorials/ibft) but it only showed deploying the network with 4 validators (in this situation, maybe Full nodes). Now I have no idea what I should do to add the light node or change the validator into the light node.